# Quartz.NET reschedule not working as expected

Tags: quartz.net

I've written the rescheduling code as shown below.  Despite the schedule saying "repeat every 120 seconds", the Execute() method keeps getting called immediately after concluding the UpdateQuartzJobTrigger method.

```cs
 class Model : IJob
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Executing Job: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            //Do some stuff
            UpdateQuartzJobTrigger(context);
        }
        private void UpdateQuartzJobTrigger( IJobExecutionContext context )
        {
            // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 120 seconds
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity(context.Trigger.Key.Name, context.Trigger.Key.Group)
              .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                  .WithIntervalInSeconds(120)
                  .RepeatForever())
              .Build();
            var result = context.Scheduler.RescheduleJob(context.Trigger.Key, trigger);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quartz.Net - delay a simple trigger to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515542/quartz-net-delay-a-simple-trigger-to-start)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, these two are far from duplicates.  The OP in your question is trying to delay triggers when **starting** a service.  I'm not trying to delay anything, I want the the trigger to get rescheduled and fire when the criteria for that schedule is met.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, a best practice would be to not combine "Execute" and then RescheduleJob.

The WithIntervalInSeconds will start "immediately"...wait X seconds, and then go again.  It does not "delay" for X seconds.

So basically, you are completing your "job", then IMMEDIATELY rescheduling it...but since there is no delay (as @AM points out), it gets rescheduled immediately.

I would separate your job-creation logic from your job-execution logic.

Or look here:

[How to do “sequential” Job Scheduling (Quartz?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486607/how-to-do-sequential-job-scheduling-quartz)

**But what you are experiencing is correct, as-designed behavior.**  WithIntervalInSeconds does not have a "delay the first execution" behavior.  It is the time between the 1st and 2nd executions....(and the 2nd and 3rd and so on and so on).

Comment: Thanks @granadacoder.  I find this behavior to be a bit odd, because there is another method in the TriggerBuilder called StartNow(), which now seems redundant if WithInterval is used.

Comment: I blame the java guys (since its a java port over) for all the quirkies!! (haha)

Answer (score 1):

The comment in your code even indicates that it supposed to `// Trigger the job to run now, and then every 120 seconds`

If you don't want it running now, then set a start time, eg

```
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity(context.Trigger.Key.Name, context.Trigger.Key.Group)
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
              .WithIntervalInSeconds(120)
              .RepeatForever())
          .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(120, IntervalUnit.Second))   
          .Build();
```